# Facing Error : TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: fullcalendar

I have added all the required Js and CSS file for FullCalander but I am still facing an error. when I remove vendors.min.js then its works. I don't know why vendors.min.js is creating the problem.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
    at GenerateCalender (Events2:271)
    at Object.success (Events2:262)
    at c (vendors.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (vendors.min.js:2)
    at l (vendors.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (vendors.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if there is any other error or warning showing in console ? Can you please post full console messages?

Comment: Can you also try to call vendors.min.js after the fullcalendar js files. And please edit the question and add some more code and script calls. Thank you.

Comment: I am calling vendors.min.js after FullCalendar.js

Comment: On console, there is only error as I mentioned in question

Comment: Please add more of your code, so we may direct you to some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your script after including your jquery library

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
    </head>
  <body>
     <div id='calendar'></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            left:   'Calendar',
            center: '',
            right:  'today prev,next'
            });

        });
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```